# Load all tables returned by Stored Procedure

Tags: vb.net

It's simple to load data from a stored procedure into a DataSet if we know exactly what tables are going to be returned:

```
Dim data As New DataSet
data.Load(reader, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges, "Apples", "Oranges", "Pears")
```

However, if we don't care what tables are returned to us, or even how many tables are returned, is it possible to simply load them all into the DataSet?

I assume not with .Load() as you need to provide table parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with sqlDataAdapter.

```
 Dim da as new SqlDataAdapter
 Dim ds as new Dataset
 da.selectCommand=com 'stored procedure
 SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(com)
 If Not ParameterValues Is Nothing Then
    For i As Integer = 1 To ParameterValues.Length
        sqlcmd.Parameters(i).Value = ParameterValues(i - 1)
    Next
 End If
 da.Fill(ds)
```

It will load all the tables which will be returned by SP